# How to convert Corel Draw design into HTML design?

Tags: html, templates, coreldraw

I have a Corel Draw .cdr file which has a full design of a web page. Is there any way to convert that design into HTML template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the .CDR into CorelDraw and export it to HTML.

Since .CDR is a proprietary file format, CorelDraw is the best at opening them without 'weirdness'.

But if you don't have CorelDraw then ([according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDR_(file_format)#CDR_file_format)) the CDR file format import is partially or fully supported in following applications:

- Adobe Illustrator - CorelDraw 5,6,7,8,9,10
- Corel PaintShop Photo Pro
- Corel WordPerfect Office
- Inkscape with UniConvertor installed; partial support
- Macromedia Freehand - CorelDraw 7, 8
- Microsoft Visio 2002 - CorelDRAW! Drawing File versions 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0 and 7.0 (.cdr), Corel Clipart (.cmx)
- sK1 - partial support
- Xara Designer Pro and Xara Photo & Graphic Designer - early versions of CorelDRAW CDR and CMX

Answer (score 0):

In CorelDraw X7 you will go to File > Export For > HTML

Otherwise HTML is not an option in the regular export menu.